# What protocol is IP(Internet Protocol) based on?

Tags: http, tcp, ip, osi

I'm new to OSI model. I know HTTP is based on TCP and TCP is based on IP. But what protocol is IP using. I can't find an article talking about it online. Can anyone help me out? Or maybe I have this all misunderstood? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't based on anything. It is the lowest level network-layer protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP uses a wide variety of layer 2 protocols for transport. Many protocols can carry IP in one way or other. Some examples are: Ethernet, Wi-Fi, ATM, Infiniband, xDSL, HDLC, PPP.